# Best approach to check a model's value against a simple list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails user model with an email field. I want to check whether the user's email is on a list of emails. Let's call it the "Guest List." I'm looking for the cleanest way to keep the guest list and check if the user is on it.

This could be an externally-maintained list (a Google sheet, CSV, etc). Or it could certainly be a table in the Rails app's database.

I was going to create the table, but I don't know the preferred way to do that for such a small task. Should I actually be creating a whole new model for Guest List? It seems like a very high-level thing to create for this one task. The Guest List will never be used for anything other than

```
if GuestList contains user:email
 do something
end
```

Any advice? Does Rails have some other feature that is good for this?

Comment: if it is EVER going to change -- take the extra minutes and create a table -- so you never have to deploy to update the list

Comment: requirements always change. a model gives you the most flexibility and it doesn't cost  anything to have an extra one. it's far easier to update and maintain than csv or external list. `bin/rails g model GuestList email:string:index` and done.

Comment: @Alex I would probally consider a differerent name through as that one implies that its a list and not *an item on the list*. `GuestListMember` for example is lot clearer.